# Powershell script from another script with multiple positional arguments

Tags: powershell

There are already some questions about how to call one PS script with arguments from another like that one
[Powershell: how to invoke a second script with arguments from a script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12850487/powershell-how-to-invoke-a-second-script-with-arguments-from-a-script)

But I'm stuck in case I have first script with multiple positional parameters.

testpar2.ps1 calls testpars.ps1

```
#$arglist=(some call to database to return argument_string)

$arglist="first_argument second_argument third_argument"

$cmd=".\testpars.ps1"

& $cmd $arglist
```

$arglist variable should be populated with string from database. This string contains arguments for testpar.ps1.

testpars.ps1 looks like

```
echo argument1 is $args[0] 
echo argument2 is $args[1] 
echo arugment3 is $args[3]

# some_command_call $arg[0] $arg[1] $arg[2]
```

This arguments should be used in testpars.ps1 in some way, like to path them to some command.

But when i run testpars2.ps1 i got

```
argument1 is first_argument second_argument third argument 
argument2 is 
arugment3 is
```

It thinks that it is one argument, not a list of them.

Comment: `echo arugment3 is $args[3]` Did you mean `$args[2]`?

Answer (score 1):

As you can see, when you pass a string to a function, PowerShell treats that as a single value.  This is usually good, because it avoids the problem in CMD of having to constantly quote and unquote strings.  To get separate values, you need to `split()` the string into an array.

```
$arglistArray = $arglist.split()
```

Now you have an array of three strings, but they're still all passed as one parameter.  PowerShell has an idea known as [splatting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj672955.aspx) to pass an array of values as multiple arguments.  To use splatting, replace the `$` with `@` in the argument list.

```
& $cmd @arglistArray
```

For more information on splatting, type `Get-Help about_Splatting`