# Why can't I use Start-Process to invoke a script with parameters?

Tags: powershell, parameters, start-process

I am trying to write a wrapper script in Powershell which is passed the name of an executable, does some preprocessing, then invokes that executable with arguments resulting from that preprocessing.  I want the executable to be anything you can run/open on Windows so I want to use `Start-Process` to run it so [Invoke a second script with arguments from a script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12850487/7685) (which references `Invoke-Expression`) isn't really relevant.  What I'm finding is that when the executable is another Powershell script, the arguments aren't seen by the script.

My stupid little test is:

```
Write-Output "Arg0: '$($Args[0])', Arg1: '$($Args[1])'" >>test.log
```

And working at a PS prompt this is what I see:

```
PS C:\Source> .\test.ps1 a b
PS C:\Source> more .\test.log
Arg0: 'a', Arg1: 'b'

PS C:\Source> .\test.ps1 c d
PS C:\Source> more .\test.log
Arg0: 'a', Arg1: 'b'
Arg0: 'c', Arg1: 'd'

PS C:\Source> Start-Process .\test.ps1 -ArgumentList e,f
PS C:\Source> Start-Process .\test.ps1 -Args e,f
PS C:\Source> more .\test.log                                                                                   
Arg0: 'a', Arg1: 'b'
Arg0: 'c', Arg1: 'd'
Arg0: '', Arg1: ''
Arg0: '', Arg1: ''

PS C:\Source>
```

Which is consistent with what I see when using `Start-Process` in a script.   I've spend a couple of hours Googling without finding an answer.  Any thoughts?

I'm working on Windows 10 for development but my target is Windows Server.  I don't know that that should make a difference.

Comment: `Start-Process .\test.ps1` treats `.\test.ps1` like a _document_, it performs the same default action you would get if you double-clicked the file in explorer (which, by default, is to open the script _for editing_). Also `Start-Process` is _asynchronous_ by default, so you'd have to pass `-Wait`. If you simply want to run a script / console application _in the same console window, synchronously_, don't use `Start-Process` at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to invoke the script through `powershell.exe`:

```
Start-Process powershell -ArgumentList "-File .\test.ps1 arg1 arg2 argX"
```

You can specify the argument list either as a string or an array of strings. [See example 7 here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-5.1#examples) for more information.

As stated by @mklement0 in the question comment, if you don't invoke it through `powershell.exe`, it will execute it in the default context as Windows thinks that `.ps1` files should be executed, which does not pass additional arguments to the script in this case.

---

You may not need to use `Start-Process` though - If you don't require any of the special functionality provided by `Start-Process` you can also just call the script using the call `&` operator or by specifying the path to the script just like you would interactively:

```
# You can use a variable with the path to the script
# in place of .\test.ps1 here and provide the arguments
# as variables as well, which lets you build a dynamic
# command out without using `Start-Process` or `Invoke-Expression`.
& .\test.ps1 arg1 arg2 argX
```

or

```
# You can use variables for the arguments here, but the script name
# must be hardcoded. Good for cases where the entrypoint doesn't change.
.\test.ps1 arg1 arg2 argX
```

---

You may also want to look into using [argument splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting?view=powershell-5.1) for your arguments as well when building out dynamic commands. [I wrote an answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56485284/584676) as well which goes over splatting in more detail.

Comment: Thanks.  `& $executable @argsArray` then testing `$?` does what I wanted.

Comment: Note that `$?` checks whether the last *cmdlet* succeeded. *External commands* (`exe` files) don't indicate success through `$?`, you have to check the value of `$LASTEXITCODE`.