# start powershell wont accept variable as parameter

Tags: powershell, variables, parameters

#### issue

the called powershell script will accept parameters but not all of them:
[image]

#### Current Set-Up and code:

I have a common folder where two `.ps1` scripts are located:

- DoWork.ps1
- Workmanager.ps1

Workmanager.ps1 calls the Dowork.ps1:

```
$targetPath="M:\target"
echo "target path: $targetPath"

start powershell {.\DoWork.ps1 -target $targetPath -tempdrive D:\}
```

output (as expected):

> target path: M:\target

DoWork.ps1 contains some start code:

```
param 
(
    [string]$tempdrive, 
    [string]$target, 
    [int] $threads = 8,
    [int] $queuelength = -1
)
echo "variables:"
echo "temp drive: $tempdrive"
echo "target path: $target"
```

Unexpectedly, the `$target` is not beeing assigned. Previously I had the variable named $targetpath, which did not work either.

> variables:
> temp drive: D:\
> target path:

#### Findings

It appears that the issue relies in Workmanager.ps1. Spcifying the parameter as fixed string rather than as variable will load the parameter. Any solution for this?

```
start powershell {.\DoWork.ps1 -target "foo" -tempdrive D:\}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a `ScriptBlock` as an argument to `powershell.exe`, variables aren't going to be evaluated until *after* the new session starts. `$targetPath` has not been set in the child PowerShell process called by `Workmanager.ps1` and so it has no value. **This is actually an expected behavior of a `ScriptBlock` in general and behaves this way in other contexts too**.

The solution is mentioned in the help text for `powershell -?`:

> ```
> [-Command { - | <script-block> [-args <arg-array>] <========== THIS GUY
>               | <string> [<CommandParameters>] } ]
> ```

You must provide the `-args` parameter which will be passed to the `ScriptBlock` on execution (separate multiple arguments with a `,`). Passed arguments are passed positionally, and must be referenced as though you were processing the arguments to a function manually using the `$args` array. For example:

```
$name = 'Bender'
& powershell { Write-Output "Hello, $($args[0])" } -args $name
```

However, especially with more complicated `ScriptBlock` bodies, having to remember which index of `$args[i]` contains the value you want at a given time is a pain in the butt. Luckily, we can use a little trick with defining parameters within the `ScriptBlock` to help:

```
$name = 'Bender'
& powershell { param($name) Write-Output "Hello, $name" } -args $name
```

This will print `Hello, Bender` as expected.

---

Some additional pointers:

- The `ScriptBlock` can be multiline as though you were defining a function. way. The examples above are single line due to their simplicity.
- A `ScriptBlock` is just an unnamed function, which is why defining parameters and referencing arguments within one works the same way.
- To exemplify this behavior outside of `powershell.exe -Command`, `Invoke-Command` requires you to pass variables to its `ScriptBlock` in a [similar fashion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8449230/584676). Note however that answer uses an already-defined function body as the `ScriptBlock` (which is totally valid to do)
- You don't need to use [`Start-Process`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/start-process?view=powershell-7.1) here (`start` is its alias), at least as demonstrated in your example. You can simply use the call operator `&` unless you need to do something more complex than "run the program and wait for it to finish". [See this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60099929/584676) for more information.
- If you opt to pass a `string` to `powershell.exe` instead, you don't need to provide arguments and your variables will get rendered in the current PowerShell process. However, **so will any other unescaped variables** that might be intended to set within the child process, so be careful with this approach. Personally, I prefer using `ScriptBlock` regardless, and just deal with the extra parameter definition and arguments.
- Using the call `&` operator is optional when you are not executing a path rendered as a string. It can be omitted in the examples above, but is more useful like so:

  ```
  & "C:\The\Program Path\Contains\spaces.exe"

  & $programPathAsAVariable
  ```