# Powershell on ansible-playbook remote host

Tags: windows, powershell, ansible

I have a PowerShell script `ex1.ps1` which takes user inputs and `ex1.ps1` has commands to open a new PowerShell to execute an `exe` file:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "$PSHOME\powershell.exe" -ArgumentList "-command C:\APPLICATION1.exe`
```

I want to execute `ex1.ps1` on a remote host. I am trying to call `ex1.ps1` using Ansible-playbook as:

```yaml
# ansible-playbook script
- name: Run basic PowerShell script
    win_powershell:
       script: |
           powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy ByPass -File C:/Users/ex1.ps1
```

It is executing fine but in remote host there is no PowerShell prompt open to get the inputs.

Comment: Please edit your question and format your code correctly using the formatting aids on top of the editor window and the help on the right side of the screen. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be expecting manual input when deploying with a tool like Ansible. I don't know the actual program you are trying to run but the best solution here is to figure out the required parameters for the program to install/start/run without user interaction.

If you are able to provide the name of the program (and it's not something internal to your organization) a more complete answer may be able to be provided.

---

Unrelated to your question, unless you've over-generalized your code for this question there isn't a reason to call `powershell.exe` from within PowerShell just to run an executable. You can either use `Start-Process` or the [call operator `&`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#call-operator-) directly with the `exe` path in question.

I have an [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60099929/584676) that goes over `Start-Process` and the usage of `&` in a bit more detail.